# Linux OpenOffice automation

Tags: javascript, ruby, linux, excel, openoffice.org

Is there simple way to automate Open Office from Ruby or Java Script on Linux?
I need to open an xls file, edit some sheets/rows, and save it as new file.

Comment: Should it automate Open Office, or just manipulate xls files?

Comment: Do you mean a "unique filename", or a "unix (??) filename"

Comment: Yes, I need automate OpenOffice, because i have some stupid xls file with VBA macroses and locked by password. I have to open it, change some cells on different sheets and save it as new file. So I need use this xls file as a template.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need openoffice. Use the ruby gem [spreadsheet](http://rubyforge.org/projects/spreadsheet/):

To install:

```
gem install spreadsheet
```

To use:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried to use `spreadsheet` gem but without success. Modified and saved xls file by this gem is not recognized by MSOffice and OOo. So i have to use some real office suite

Comment: If you succeeded up to reading and modifying it, and you do not have formatting, then the rest is not difficult. You can output as a csv file, open it from either MSOffice or OOo, and save as xls.

Comment: This xls file provided by Ministry of Law of Singapore as template and contain VBA macroses and some cells locked by password. I have to keep all formatting and VBA macroses. CSV file is unsuitable case. 
Of course i should make this operations in my ruby program (not by hands) - as "Generate report for Government"

Comment: Then you should work on excel macro and automate things on the xsl file. I don't think there is a ruby library that can follow excel macros.

Comment: Yes, Thats why i ask about OOo automation. I know about UNO - this is something like MS COM model for OOo. There is UNO libs for perl, python and php, but not for ruby (there is ruby uno lib for win32 thats unsuitable for me).

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. Sorry.